# Observing Data (image/array/etc)

Tags: computer-vision

Consider the following image:

[image]

As far as I can think, a computer will have to check every cell to see if it contains the green dot.

I.e.

```
(0,0) //false
(0,1) //false
(0,2) //false
...
(14,18) //true
```

With that, we humans, do not need to scan each cell independently to find the green dot. 
In fact we can immediately say "It's near the bottom right corner"

Is there any way/approach to have a computer see the same grid more like humans do?

I would love to get some reading references!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right what you are asking for is how to process all the cells in parallel. Techniques that you might want to have a look at are referred to as *deep learning* (especially *convolutional neural networks,* or *CNNs*). They process images in parallel but in separate layers (steps) that are sometimes compared to the layers of neurons in the optical cortex.

There is a good introductory book on the subject at http://www.deeplearningbook.org/